# What is the point/purpose of SageMaker Experiments tracker and add_trial_component methods?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Given that SageMaker Experiments automatically creates trial components for SM training jobs, what is the point/purpose of the tracker API and its `add_trial_component` method?

Is this for monitoring things other than SageMaker Training jobs? (if yes, can you provide examples?)